# How to set input value with JS

Tags: javascript

I have input :

```
<input type="text"  id="nameProduct">
```

I want set value :

```
document.getElementById("nameProduct").value="hello";
```

How can I do it before page  load input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't do it with JavaScript**, the dom element object can only get after it loaded. The right way is to set value attribute for input.

```html
<input type="text" id="nameProduct" value="hello">
```

---

A simple hack you can do is hide element initially and show it after value updated using JavaScript.

```js
var ele=document.getElementById("nameProduct");
ele.value="hello";
ele.style.display='block';
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nameProduct" style="display:none">
```

Comment: No, I must do it in JS

Comment: I get a variable from other page and when I load this page I must set a variable in my input with js